# jQuery - Cross domain request does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to get some data via `$.ajax`. I only need the response (the response is in JSON).
This is what I have now:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "example.com",
processData: true,
data: {},
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
  alert(data);
} 
});
```

...but I always get an error with origin or so, so I changed my code to

```
... dataType: "jsonp"
```

... but now I get the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

What am I doing wrong? I am NOT able  to change headers or .htaccess stuff because I have no access on the target server.

Thank you.

Comment: If the server isn't configured to allow your request, you'll have to create a proxy on your own server. There's no other workaround. (The error you're getting just means that the server is returning just JSON, not JSONP.)

Comment: @Pointy but with PHP it works!

Comment: @JamesThorpe no, there is one.

Comment: @krmax44 yes, that would be an example of creating "a proxy on your own server."

Comment: @Pointy crap, than I'll have to take this. Thank you.

Comment: As for `jsonp` itself, the server will return basically Javascript (function name with data in parameter). But I would go take a look at [tag:cors] with whatever is happening on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Please use full URL instead of "example.com" Like
"http://www.domainname.com/example.com

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "example.com",
processData: true,
data: {},
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
 alert(data);
} 
});
```

Comment: I did this in my project but not here; does not work.